# Connectivity issues when calling a controller endpoint, how can we deal with it? [Spring and Kotlin]

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, model-view-controller

I have some service method used in my controller endpoint whose logic is not fully executed when connectivity issues arise (as you would expect). I am looking for a potential approach, rather than using a try and catch block within the service method. What is the recommended way to go? Is there any "rollback" functionality that can be injected in Spring whereby if something happens during the executing of the service logic then it rolls back?

Thank you

Comment: Did you look into spring-retry?

Comment: Thank you, I actually did after your comment. It looks rather good. I also noticed that we had a misuse of @Transactional in our codebase that we need to address.